# emberjs + gojs integration

Tags: ember.js, gojs

Hey guys I am trying out emberjs and want to integrate goJS to it. I did an npm install of the package https://www.npmjs.com/package/gojs
But I can't find any good documentation on this.. so if anyone can point out my error that will be great

```
import Component from "@glimmer/component";
import go from "gojs";
import { action } from "@ember/object";
import { tracked } from "@glimmer/tracking";

export default class GraphComponent extends Component {
  @tracked iconName = "check-circle";

  $ = go.GraphObject.make;
  myDiagram = $(go.Diagram, "myDiagramDiv");



  @action
  changeIcon() {
    if (this.iconName == "check-circle") {
      this.iconName = "sync-alt";
    } else {
      this.iconName = "check-circle";
    }
  }
}
```

This is my ember component graph.js and In graph.hbs I have the corresponding div but some how nothing shows up on the screen. am I missing something ?

And would also appreciate any links to a goJS with emberJS docs.TY

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend to utilize the [`didInsert` render modifier](https://github.com/emberjs/ember-render-modifiers).

With this you can do

```
<div id="myDiagramDiv" {{did-insert this.insertDiagram}}></div>
```

and then you can have an action that will run after the div was inserted to the DOM:

```
@action
insertDiagram() {
  const $ = go.GraphObject.make;
  const myDiagram = $(go.Diagram, "myDiagramDiv");
}
```

otherwise you will run this code before the `<div>` is avaliable.